# Shopify: Variant image switches to featured image upon page refresh

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I inherited a heavily customized Shopify website and am struggling with a strange issue. I implemented a forced-page refresh when someone changes variants in order to make the in-stock information display correctly.

Now, when you switch from one variant to another, the correct image briefly appears and then refreshes back to the featured image.  When you click 'Yellow Gold' the yellow gold image shows for a milisecond and then dissapears.

https://nicolehdjewelry.com/collections/bracelets/products/diamond-quatrefoil-bracelet

Tried adding/altering several different scripts to the product.liquid page to no avail.